# Android Studio gender Analysis app:How to create an android app to do gender analysis on a photo. Any tutorials which helps to create an app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv, android-fragments

I am new to android app development. I have created some simple apps recently. Now I want to create an app for gender analysis on a photo. The app should work like this, it should take a photo save it and perform gender analysis on the photo. I have heard about open cv but not sure where to start. Can someone please post any link to these kind of tutorials.

Comment: What makes you think you can guess gender from a photo anyway?  The one and only way to determine someone's gender is for them to tell you.

Comment: This is one of the interview questions, to create an app for gender analysis. I had seen some youtube videos of apps doing the same using opencv. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUb_zKfrheg.  Is there a way or tutorial i can follow to create an app as in the youtube link i have mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find something ready made, which you could directly use in android application to detect the gender from the image.
Learn image processing first. You will have to create your own algorithm to process the image to figure out if the person is a man or woman. For example, detect if the person has long hair, if the person is wearing a make-up, if ear-rings are present, etc
Ones you develop that module, integrating it in an android application should be straight forward.